Как исправить ошибку «cannot load certificate» после удаления сертификата letsencrypt?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, установил сертификат с помощью certbot в облачном сервере на Ubuntu, но установил с ошибкой и затем удалил его через команду certbot delete --cert-name домен. После попытался выпустить новый сертификат через команду certbot. Но вышла ошибка
3186#3186: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/домен/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory:calling fopen(/etc/letsencrypt/live/домен/fullchain.pem, r) error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Если правильно понял, то я нарушил шаги удаления сертификата, надо было сначало выполнить команду
certbot revoke --cert-path /etc/letsencrypt/live/домен/cert.pem

Любая команда nginx выдаёт ту же ошибку. Перезагрузка nginx systemctl restart nginx выдаёт ошибку Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code
При запуске команды certbot выдаёт ошибку
5156#5156: open() "/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:147
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
server {
        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name site.ru; # managed by Certbot


        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = site.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name site.ru;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

Как исправть данную ошибку и выпустить заново сертификат на тот же домен?

Убрать использование сертификата из конфига nginx. Раз certbot не сделал этого сам — значит вручную

@andreymal Подскажите, пожалуйста, а из какого именно нужно удалить, тк там их несколько /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
events {    worker_connections 768; } http {  sendfile on;  tcp_nopush on;  types_hash_max_size 2048;  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;  default_type application/octet-stream;  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;  gzip on;  application/xml application/xml+rss text/jav>  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; }
